# What is the best situation to remove deprecated functions dependency from Java 11

Tags: java, deprecated, java-11, deprecation-warning

I am upgrading my application to support java 11. When should I remove the deprecated functions like new Integer(String)?

There are some places where our application used statement like `Integer iVar = new Integer("1")` in my code, which is showing as deprecated in Java 11. Is it the best time to remove the deprecated code now itself or can we wait for sometime

Basically, I need some help when these type of code could be completely removed from Java

Comment: What about `Integer iVar = Integer.parseInt(s)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is completly safe to remove the function in your example. Reading the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#<init>(java.lang.String)) says:

> Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Use
>   **parseInt(String)** to convert a string to a int primitive, or use
>   **valueOf(String)** to convert a string to an Integer object.

In your example: `Integer iVar = Integer.valueOf("1")`

There is really no point to create a new instance of Integer every time.

In each case of a deprecated method, you have to read the documentation and look for the replacements. Better sooner than later.

Comment: Woulnd't be `Integer.valueOf (1);` be much better, as it is type checked by the compile and can't throw a NumberFormatException? Or is this only an option, which appeared 2020, later than your posting?

Comment: In that case yes. I assumed that `"1"` is just a placeholder for any arbitrary `String`.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it the best time to remove the deprecated code now itself or can we wait for sometime*

Most of such deprecation suggests an alternate way of cleanly implementing the same. You should just follow them and clean up your code.

If it doesn't lead to a satisfactory (usable) enough jar (or any other archive) ultimately is when you can decide to uphold them and not to upgrade further Java versions.

To add to it, [`forRemoval` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Deprecated.html#forRemoval()) of `@Deprecated` annotation added since Java-9 should be an indication of such attributes about to be removed ideally.